# Manual Mock of Javascript module using jest, when the module is a directory with entry file (index.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm having trouble manually mocking es6 classes when they are exported from a module which is a directory. According to the Jest [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules), creating a __mocks__ directory with files for each desired mocked module, adjacent to those modules should do the trick. For instance:

```
models/
  __mocks__/
    - A.js
  - A.js
  - B.js
  - B.spec.js

// __mocks__/A.js
   const A = jest.fn().mockImplementation();
   A.prototype.foo = jest.fn(); 
   module.exports = A;

// B.spec.js
  jest.mock('./A');
  const A = require('A');
  console.log(A.prototype.foo); // [Function: mockConstructor] { ... }
```

The above file structure and implementation work swimmingly. However, when **A** lives in its own node module with an entry file, the mock implementation breaks.

```
models/
  __mocks__/
    - A.js
  A/
    - index.js
  - B.js
  - B.spec.js

// B.spec.js
jest.mock('./A');
const A = require('./A');
console.log(A.prototype.foo) // undefined
```

Is there any way to mock a node module in this fashion, when this is the file structure of the project?

Comment: Did you try `__mocks__/A/index.js` and `jest.mock('__mocks__/A/index.js')`?

Comment: @EstusFlask this did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by putting the `__mocks__` directory inside the directory that contains `index.js`. So for you, the structure would be:

```
models/
  A/
    - index.js
    __mocks__/
       - index.js
  - B.js
  - B.spec.js
```

Comment: Hey! sorry this took so long for me to get back to you. I swore I had already tried this, but i guess not - it worked!! really appreciate the help.